# arm instruction is 'UNDEFINED'?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am debugging an ARM program(android) and make some modify for it. I want to jmp 0x8684 in 0x8436, So I overwrite 4 bytes blx instruction, after that I use IDA pro to load the program, and it seems successful from IDA's view:

```
IDA view
-----------------------------------------------------------------
.text:00008430    LDR     R0, =(aOkkkkkkk___ - 0x8438)
.text:00008432    PUSH    {R4,LR}
.text:00008434    ADD     R0, PC  ; "okkkkkkk..."
.text:00008436    BLX     sub_8684
.text:0000843A    POP     {R4,PC}

HEX view(the machine code)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
00008436  00 F0 25 E9
```

However, the program failed to run(the src program runs normally):

```
arm-eabi-gdb
-----------------------------------------------------------------
(gdb) x/10i 0x8430
=> 0x8430:      ldr     r0, [pc, #8]    ; (0x843c)
   0x8432:      push    {r4, lr}
   0x8434:      add     r0, pc
   0x8436:                      ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xf000e925
   0x843a:      pop     {r4, pc}

(gdb) x/10x 0x8436
   0x8436: 0xe925f000      0x001cbd10
```

So the machine code of blx instruction is wrong? Please help me... I want to know the right instruction and the arithmetic to convert blx to machine code...

And the **original instructions(runs normally)** here:

```
ori:
.text:00008430    LDR   R0, =(aOkkkkkkk___ - 0x8438)
.text:00008432    PUSH  {R4,LR}
.text:00008434    ADD   R0, PC  ; "okkkkkkk..."
.text:00008436    BLX   sub_83F0
.text:0000843A    POP   {R4,PC}

ori:
00008430  02 48 10 B5  78 44 FF F7  DC EF 10 BD

modified:
00008430  02 48 10 B5  78 44 00 F0  25 E9 10 BD
```

Comment: please provide more disassembly, the blx instruction is 32 bits on thumb or arm (technically the thumb is two separate 16 bit instructions) so if you replaced the thumb instruction with the arm version then it will no doubt break.  For all of the assembly you have shown here please provide the disassembly for both the before and after versions

Comment: or the machine code if that is easier. whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
00008436  00 F0 26 E9

0xF000 111 10 00000000000 first half, immed 00000000000
0xE926 111 01 00100100110 second half, blx, immed 00100100110

0x8436 + 0b0000000000000100100110<<1 + 2 =
0x8436 + 0x24C + 2 = 
0x8684
```

From the ARM Architectural Reference Manual (ARM ARM).

```
if H == 10 then
LR = PC + (SignExtend(offset_11) << 12)
```

The PC is always two instructions ahead, this is thumb code and basically that means 2 bytes head, 16 bits, so for 0x8436 the PC is 0x8436+2

First instruction

```
0xF000 111 10 00000000000 first half, immed 00000000000
LR = 0x8436+2 + 0b00000000000_000000000000
LR = 0x8438
```

Second instruction

```
0xE926 111 01 00100100110 second half, blx, immed 00100100110

if H == 01 then 
 PC = (LR + (offset_11 << 1)) AND 0xFFFFFFFC 
 LR = (address of next instruction) | 1 
 CPSR T bit = 0

PC = (0x8438 + 0b00100100110_0)&0xFFFFFFFC
PC = (0x8438 + 0x0000024C)&0xFFFFFFFC
PC = (0x8684)&0xFFFFFFFC
PC = 0x8684
LR = 0x843A | 1
LR = 0x843B
```

Learn something new every day and this is probably why nobody uses blx.  You can only use this to branch to arm from thumb.  And ARM blx only from ARM to thumb.  bl you use for staying in the same mode and BX it depends on the address, so you dont have to know ahead of time.

Comment: 0436   00 F0 26 E9  
->  
(gdb) x/10i 0x8436  

0x8436:      blx     0x8684

Comment: I change to "00 f0 26 e9" rather than "00 f0 25 e9" and the program runs ok and gdb shows it will jmp to 0x8684. But why? The arithmetic of blx's machine code puzzle me...

Comment: Thank you. ARM is really very different from x86.

Comment: they are all the same, you take the program counter you add an offset from the instruction.  most use the pc after the instruction, some use the pc before/of the instruction.

Comment: I wouldn't say nobody uses BLX - often code within a program will be thumb mode, but external or dynamic library interface code will be ARM, and so it will show up in those calls.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, Neil's attempt was targeting the wrong address by mistaking the applicable current address, and as the destination mode will be ARM the target address must be 4-byte aligned, so the misaligned mistaken address was causing  the dissembler to consider the instruction invalid?

Comment: fair enough, I dont see compilers generating blx, lets put it that way, and actually I rarely see it and have wondered for many years why...I dont know what the real problem was or if it was solved, I am clueless...

Comment: blx is found often in Android-arm binaries - function bodies are by default thumb but the procedure linkage table and some of the aebi helper code are both ARM.  I wouldn't be surprised if that was true of arm-linux in general (though android has its own C library).  I'm also seeing the register variety of blx in some code from an old bare-metal cortex m4 project, but it's not as easy to figure out what the targets are.

Comment: how would you use it on a cortex-m4, there is no arm mode?

Comment: The register variety of blx (what was mentioned on the cortex m4) does not necessarily change mode.  Register values that would are, unsurprisingly, faults on devices without an arm mode.